# Flex 3 Bind a Boolean with a condition in .as

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I want to bind in actionscript a boolean with a condition. This is possible in mxml but how can this be done on actionscript?

Example:

.mxml binding:

```
enabled={(A_changed || B_changed  || C_changed || D_changed) &amp;&amp; rs.selectedIndex !=-1}/>
```

.as binding:

```
BindingUtils.bindProperty(this.myBtn,'enabled',????);
```

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lazy solution to your issue - the Flex compiler is doing a lot of transformations in the MXML bindings, which aren't available in vanilla AS3. You'll have to attach [BindingUtils.bindSetter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/binding/utils/BindingUtils.html#bindSetter%28%29) to all of the properties. Something like:

```
var closure:Function = function(...triggers):void {
     enabled = (A_changed || B_changed || C_changed || D_changed) && rs.selectedIndex !=-1;
}
BindingUtils.bindSetter(closure, this, "A_changed");
BindingUtils.bindSetter(closure, this, "B_changed");
BindingUtils.bindSetter(closure, this, "C_changed");
BindingUtils.bindSetter(closure, this, "D_changed");
BindingUtils.bindSetter(closure, rs, "selectedIndex");
```